# How to reference virtual machine name of VMSS in JSON template

Tags: json, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there a way to reference a VM name that is deployed in VM Scale Set? I'm using custom script extension that runs install script when each VM in scale set is deployed and for one of the parameters of the script I want to use a name of the VM. For single instance it was easy:

```
"commandToExecute": "[concat('sh ap-cluster-setup.sh -h=',parameters('virtualMachineName'),' -s=',parameters('subnetAddressPrefix'),'')]"
```

but since VM name in scale set is created dynamically when it is deployed I can't think of a way to reference it in JSON. The VM naming convention is vmssTemplate_0, vmssTemplate_1, etc. where vmssTemplate is parameters('virtualMachineScaleSets_name') in VMSS template.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in the template itself since the same parameters get passed to each VM on script execution. However, You should be able to figure out the VM name from within the script. For instance, on a Linux machine you could use the `hostname` command, which will return the VM name. Does this meet your needs?

Comment: I've thought about this but I'm concerned about `hostname` because as far as I know the Custom Extension runs scripts when VM is being deployed so I don't know if this command will be available and if it will return correct value. But I guess I just have to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

> where vmssTemplate is parameters('virtualMachineScaleSets_name') in
>   VMSS template.

We can find where vmss template define the Virtual machine's name.
**computernameprefix**:

```
"osProfile": {
            "computerNamePrefix": "[variables('namingInfix')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
          },
```

and the 'namingInfix' define here:

```
 "namingInfix": "[toLower(substring(concat(parameters('vmssName'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)), 1, 9))]",
```

By default the VMSS with autoscale settings, and the vm's name should be create automatically.

If you want to get the VMs' name, we can use powershell to get it:

```
PS C:\windows> Get-AzureRmVmssVM -ResourceGroupName YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME -VMScaleSetName YOUR_VMSS_NAME
```

Also you can add some script (to get the name of your VMs) in your script, then upload the script to custom script extension.

Comment: This is totally understandable and I've even found template that utilizes this approach https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vmss-ubuntu-autoscale/azuredeploy.json but I don't think that this is a way to reference the VM name that is part of VMSS in a template. It is just a way to set the prefix of a VM.